# Can I disable a combo box or dtp based on the value of a text box that's in another class?

Tags: c#, class, combobox, datetimepicker

Beginner question but any help would be really appreciated.

Can I disable a combo box or dtp based on the value of a text box that's in another class?

I have a date/time picker that I want to disable if a text box from another class has any value in it.

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: What's the scope of your objects ? Can you clarify by providing code samples ?

Comment: Sorry !! Can you give extra details??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way would be with an event with something like that:

```
private void ReadWriteTB_TextChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (condition)
        comboBox.Enabled = false;

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I would like to do, but I am unable to access txtcount (the textbox), it is not coming up in intellisense, while in the class that contains the combobox that I would like to disable.

Comment: You can expose it with a property. `public TextBox YourTextBox { get { return txtcount; }}`. This way you can do `YourClass.YourTextBox.Enabled = false`.